# How to format numbers? php function

Tags: php, numbers, format

I need help formatting the result from `get_order_total()`, It needs to have commas and periods like 1,000.00 because I am dealing with numbers.

I am new to PHP, here is my code:

```
    function get_order_total(){
      $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
      $sum=0;
      for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
        $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
        $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
        $price=get_price($pid);
        $sum+=$price*$q;
      }
     return $sum;  
   }
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at the php `number_format` function

Comment: You can achieve that using php's number_format() function. http://nl1.php.net/number_format

Comment: Why the javascript tag?

Comment: Even [BING](http://www.bing.com/search?q=How+to+format+numbers+in+php&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=how+to+format+numbers+in+php&sc=2-28&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=d94c92d830354ba8850923a353761952) returns the correct answer...

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using [number_format()](http://php.net/number_format). For example:

```
$num = 1000;
echo number_format($num,2); // 1,000.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Use php [number_format](https://www.php.net/number_format).
Try this code:

```
 function get_order_total(){
      $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
      $sum=0;
      for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
        $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
        $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
        $price=get_price($pid);
        $sum+=$price*$q;
      }
     return number_format($sum);  
   }
```